# Display results, which have three different values in common and the next result is at least twice as big

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, relational-division

So i have following problem:
The Database is the Sakila Sample Database in MySQL, but I'm using postgreSQL.
I have to display the films, which have at least different actors in common:

```
select f1.film_id, f1.title
from film f1
join film_actor fa1 on f1.film_id = fa1.film_id
join film_actor fa2 on f1.film_id = fa2.film_id
join film_actor fa3 on f1.film_id = fa3.film_id
where ((fa1.actor_id <> fa2.actor_id) and (fa2.actor_id <> fa3.actor_id) and  (fa1.actor_id <> fa3.actor_id))
```

This is what I tried, but I can't find a way to select the Result with have the three Actor_ids in common. And the next thing is, the value rental_rate has to be twice as high for the following movies,
I'm not allowed to use Group By or count. 
I would put the first query as a "exists" subquery
and the first would contain something like:

```
select f1.film_id, f1.title
from film f1
join film f2 on f1.film_id = f2.film_id
where f1.rental_rate > 2 * f2.film_id
```

But I'm still a beginner and can't figure out 
both as seperate conditions.
The result would be :

```
film id title
6 AGENT TRUMAN
9 ALABAMA DEVIL
10 ALADDIN CALENDAR
...
```

and it would have exactly 101 rows

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as an aggregation. This query counting the number of actors in common between two films is a good place to start:

```
select fa1.film_id, fa2.film_id, count(*) as num_actors_in_common
from film_actor fa1 join
     film_actor fa2
     on fa2.actor_id = fa1.actor_id 
group by fa1.film_id, fa2.film_id;
```